# Neural Network from scratch for Iris Data

Tags: pandas, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to code a neural network using only numpy and pandas. I am having issues with the dimension of my data. I am getting the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (150,) (150,3)
." Not sure what the alternative is here, as we are trying to predict one of the three types of flower based on 4 numerical values. Here is my code:

````
import pandas as pd

class NeuralNet():
    def __init__(self, i_dim, h_dim, o_dim, lr):
        self.i_dim = i_dim
        self.h_dim = h_dim
        self.o_dim = o_dim
        self.lr = lr

        self.weights1 = np.random.randn(self.i_dim, self.h_dim) / np.sqrt(self.i_dim)
        self.bias1 = np.zeros((1, self.h_dim))
        self.weights2 = np.random.randn(self.h_dim, self.o_dim) / np.sqrt(self.h_dim)
        self.bias2 = np.zeros((1, self.o_dim))

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def softmax(self, x):
        exps = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
        return exps / np.sum(exps, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    def forward(self, X):
        self.layer1 = self.sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.weights1) + self.bias1)
        self.layer2 = self.softmax(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2) + self.bias2)
        return self.layer2

    def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def softmax_derivative(self, x):
        s = x.reshape(-1, 1)
        return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)

    def backward(self, X, y, y_hat):
        d_softmax = self.softmax_derivative(y_hat)
        d_sigmoid = self.sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)

        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2 * (y - y_hat) * d_softmax))
        d_bias2 = np.sum(2 * (y - y_hat) * d_softmax, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        d_weights1 = np.dot(X.T, (np.dot(2 * (y - y_hat) * d_softmax, self.weights2.T) * d_sigmoid))
        d_bias1 = np.sum(np.dot(2 * (y - y_hat) * d_softmax, self.weights2.T) * d_sigmoid, axis=0)

        self.weights1 -= self.lr * d_weights1
        self.bias1 -= self.lr * d_bias1
        self.weights2 -= self.lr * d_weights2
        self.bias2 -= self.lr * d_bias2

    def cross_ent_loss(self):
        sample_losses = - self.y * np.log(self.y_hat) - (1 - self.y) * np.log(1 - self.y_hat)
        loss = np.mean(sample_losses)
        return loss

    def train(self, X, y, epochs):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            y_hat = self.forward(X)
            self.backward(X, y, y_hat)
            loss = self.cross_ent_loss()
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss = {loss}")
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss = {loss}")

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.forward(X)

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/brasilgu/PycharmProjects/NNfs/venv/lib/iris.data.txt', header=None)

X_train = df.iloc[:, :4].values
y_train = df.iloc[:, -1].values

nn = NeuralNet(4, 5, 3, 0.1)
nn.train(X_train, y_train, 1000)

y_pred = nn.predict(X_train)

y_pred_labels = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

print(y_pred) ```



The stacktrace of the error:

``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brasilgu/PycharmProjects/NNfs/venv/lib/neural_net.py", line 72, in <module>
    nn.train(X_train, y_train, 1000)
  File "/Users/brasilgu/PycharmProjects/NNfs/venv/lib/neural_net.py", line 57, in train
    self.backward(X, y, y_hat)
  File "/Users/brasilgu/PycharmProjects/NNfs/venv/lib/neural_net.py", line 39, in backward
    d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2 * (y - y_hat) * d_softmax))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (150,) (150,3)```
````

Comment: If you could show the stacktrace of that error that will greatly improve your question.

Comment: Most likely the error was with one of the operators in `(y - y_hat) * d_softmax`.  Check the shapes of the variables, and read up on `numpy` `broadcasting` (and `shape` if you aren't clear about that).

Comment: You might want to revisit the Numpy user guide page about array shape compatibility and broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html, as well as the docs page for `numpy.dot` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html which describes the various behaviors when various array shapes are used.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the publicly available iris dataset and according to your code, the `y` seems to be a rank one matrix with shape `(150, )`.

So modify your `y_train` as `y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)` to make it a proper matrix before creating the `NeuralNet`

Comment: Hmm... I did that and now I'm getting other error ;(

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: is there a way to post my updated code? I could tell you the error but it would be lacking context.